# How do I calculate for the power serie $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k2^k}z^k$ the development point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and convergence radius?

Tags: power-series

How do I calculate for the power serie $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k2^k}z^k$ the development point $z_0\in \mathbb{C}$ and convergence radius $R\in \left [ 0,\infty \right ]$?

Comment: What is the definition of "the development point" in connection with a power series?  I've heard of a power series expansion *centered at* a point $z_0$, but I'm not familiar with the term you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) This is a series in powers of $z = z - 0$, so $z_0 = 0$.

2) Use the Ratio Test.